# How to generate waze meetup link with web fallback?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, meetup

I want to sent to the users of a website an email with a link to navigate to a Waze location. I'm using an URL like this one:

```
http://waze.to/?ll=9.9397690,-84.1442870&navigate=yes
```

And it works pretty good, but the problem is that when the user doesn't have Waze installed, the browser will just display an error, saying that wasn't able to handle that URL.

However, Waze can provide links with a kind of *fallback* to their website, and it looks like this:

```
http://mobile-web.world.waze.com/en_GB/meetup/location?h=d1u0rvny3
```

But it uses and a single `h` argument, instead of latitude and longitude. So, how can I generate (in a web server) a link with a location specified by that `h` argument (like the second one)?

Comment: That h parameter appears to be a geohash: http://geohash.org/d1u0rvny3

This may be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Comment: @TomKiley Your comment should be put as an answer. It helped.